# Context Menu in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

in Electron, is there a way to detected the element that the context menu is being clicked on?

```
menu.append(new MenuItem({ label: 'Automate',visible : ?? }))
```

I want to enable this menuItem only when it is being clicked on a div with #file as the id.

Answer (score 1):

The context menu event have a target property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu

```
element.addEventListener('contextmenu', (clickedElement) => {
  if( clickedElement.target.id === "id"){
    // show menu
   }
}
```